# Find files less than 1 week old with match TODO in files

Tags: grep, find, perl

My unsuccessful proposal

```
find ./ -newerct '1 week ago' -print | grep TODO
```

No output although should be.

Files are text files like

```
Lorem
% TODO check this out
Lorem ipsun
```

**How can you find less than 1 week old files matching TODO?** 
Output should be the line after TODO. 
Perl solution is also welcome, since I am practising it too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change this:

```
find ./ -newerct '1 week ago' -print | grep TODO
```

to this:

```
find ./ -newerct '1 week ago' -exec grep TODO {} +
```

or this:

```
find ./ -newerct '1 week ago' -print | xargs grep TODO
```

**Explanation**

Your `grep` doesn't interpret the output of `find` as a list of files to search through, but rather as its input. That is, `grep` tries to match `TODO` in the *names* of files rather than their *contents*.

From the `grep(1)` man page:

> grep  searches the named input FILEs (or standard input if no files are
>          named, or if a single hyphen-minus (-) is given as file name)

To match the line after `TODO`:

```
find ./ -newerct '1 week ago' -exec grep -A1 TODO {} + | grep -v TODO
```

This assumes you have GNU `grep`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
find . -type f -ctime -7 -print | grep -R "TODO" /etc/
```

`-type f`  -type f to list only files

`-ctime -7` is for files with a created time less than 7 days old

Answer (score 0):

You can use that:

```
find ./ -type f -newerct '1 week ago' -exec sh -c "grep -H -A1 TODO {} | tail -1" \;
```

**Explanation:**

- `-type f`: includes only files in the search pattern
- `-exec sh -c "..."`: executes ... for all found files
- `grep -H -A1 TODO {} | tail -1`: `-H` prints the filename, `-A1` prints the line after the match, and `tail -1` deletes the first line (the line with TODO) out of the output.